# How do I write a JUnit 5 test to cover the line that bootstraps a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I have the following for my class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AdminConsoleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But when I try to create a JUnit like:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;


public class AdminConsoleApplicationTests {
    @MockBean
    private SpringApplication springApplication;

    @Test
    public void main_startsSpringApplication() {
        String[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"};
        AdminConsoleApplication.main(args);
        // Verify that the SpringApplication.run method was called with the correct arguments
        verify(springApplication.run());
    }
}
```

I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(String[])" because
> "this.springApplication" is null

What is the proper way to handle this?

I also tried

```
verify(springApplication).run(AdminConsoleApplication.class, args);
```

But I got

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(String[])" because
> "this.springApplication" is null

Comment: You may want to look into @SpringBootTest instead, it's intended to bootstrap the app.

Comment: I understand that but that isn't going to work unless I can still test this line. It isn't that I don't know how to use that I just don't think it will help me test this line. I am fine with using it on other tests for DI

Comment: `@MockBean` by itself doesn't do anything, and using it for your Spring Boot application itself won't bootstrap the application, so doing this makes no sense. You want to read the chapter [Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing) of the Spring Boot Core Features documentation

Comment: Thanks I will read it this was just suggested is there a better way to handle this?